# AVPlayer seekToTime -- finished is NO -- Can't get player to play again

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm using the `AVPlayer` method:

```
    - (void)seekToTime:(CMTime)time
   toleranceBefore:(CMTime)toleranceBefore
    toleranceAfter:(CMTime)toleranceAfter
 completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completionHandler
```

for scrubbing a video. `toleranceBefore` and `toleranceAfter` are both 0.

However, when the user scrubs to within about 5 seconds of the end, on certain videos, `finished` is always equal to `NO`.

The player will then be in an inconsistent state where `pause` and `play` methods do nothing. The video is frozen at the time passed to `seekToTime`.

This happens consistently on some videos, and not at all on others.

I have a simple if/else but I don't know what to put in the else to get the player to play again:

```
[_avPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                  toleranceBefore:toleranceBefore
                   toleranceAfter:toleranceAfter
                completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {

            if(finished){

            }
            else {
              // How to get the player to play again??
            }

   }];
```

Like I said above, I've tried putting `_avPlayer play` in there but it doesn't play.

Comment: I think it has something to do with your video encoding. Did you try it with any other video?

Comment: @MKoosej It happens consistently with some videos and with others it doesn't happen at all.

Comment: that shows that may be the cause of the problem. Also if you use AVUrlAsset set AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey in the options.